# Запуск TestCase несколько раз с разными логинами/паролями

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Есть код:

```
import unittest
...
class TestCase_05_SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        login_function(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Как мне запустить TestCase_05_SomeTest с разными логинами/паролями и где их лучше хранить? Естественно, у меня не один тест кейс и не один шаг. Объединять в TestSuite пока нет необходимости (хотя предложение по решению такой задачи тоже принимается).

Comment: В нашем phpшном захолустье это решается через dataProvider'ы, и вот [реализация на питоне](http://melp.nl/2011/02/phpunit-style-dataprovider-in-python-unit-test/).

Comment: Хм, занятно, но в моем случае не получится повесить декоратор на функцию setUpClass, это будет бессмысленно, т.к. если это все же сделать, то она будет запускаться несколько раз перед запуском всех тестов данного тест кейса, и тесты будут исполнены только с последним указанным логином/паролем, я так подозреваю.

Comment: @_Александр_, если setUpClass - это метод подготовки класса к тестированию, то никакие `login_function` там точно вызываться не должны. Это работа подготовки функции к конкретному тесту, который "спонсируется" data provider-ом, или даже самого теста. Насколько понимаю, вы вообще пытаетесь реализовать сценарий интеграционного/acceptance-тестирования, и ему в юнит-тестах вообще не место.

Comment: т.е. предлагаешь в каждом тесте логиниться? по моему не самое изящное решение, учитывая что у меня > 50 тестов... должно быть другое решение, я так думаю

Comment: @_Александр_, что тут неизящно - так это запихивание функциональных или интеграционных тестов в модульные. Модульные тесты предназначены для изолированного тестирования отдельных участков кода, и перед каждым тестом **рекомендуется** производить действия, обеспечивающие обнуление окружения.

Я вообще уж молчу, что это тесты и там-то никакой заботы о ресурсах быть не должно.

Comment: А где тут модульные тесты? И чем плохо сначала залогиниться, а потом прогонять все тесты? В моем случае именно так и надо делать, не вижу смысла каждый раз логиниться; я что-то тебя не понимаю...

Comment: @_Александр_

> а где тут модульные тесты?

    import unittest

Comment: Мне надо протестировать веб сервис, я могу и руками его затестить, но вижу более удобное для меня решение, использовав unittest.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

А если вынести логины/пароли в отдельный файл конфигурации в виде массива и вызывать их уже оттуда?

Скажем, если необходимо использовать пользователей с определенными свойствами (привилегии, типы и пр.), то указывать их в качестве ключевого параметра.

А если вам нужно вызывать проверять на всех пользователях, то вызывать в качестве цикла по массиву логинов.

Все зависит от условий.

Comment: Это все очевидно, меня интересует конкретная реализация.